# Problema para convertir de factor a date en un Data Frame en R?

Tags: r

Cada vez que intento convertir un factor a un date en un DataFrame(data) me devuelve "NA" en los valores factor, en el ejemplo que muestro str(data) me devuelve que el campo DATE es factor.

```
data$DATE <- as.Date(data$DATE,format="%Y/%m/%d %H")

DATE            OBJ    No
2018-09-24-00   Leo     12
2018-09-24-00   Jhon    12
2018-09-24-02   Ale     13
2018-09-24-00   Juan    13
2018-09-24-04   Duas    13
2018-09-24-05   Doi     76
2018-09-24-06   Doi     78
2018-09-24-07   Doi     80
2018-09-24-08   Doi     82
2018-09-24-09   Doi     84
2018-09-24-00   Doi     86
2018-09-24-11   Doi     88
2018-09-24-12   Doi     90
2018-09-24-13   Doi     92
2018-09-24-14   Doi     94
2018-09-24-15   Doi     96
2018-09-24-16   Doi     98
2018-09-24-17   Doi     100
2018-09-24-18   Doi     102
2018-09-24-19   Doi     104
```

Y me devuelve

```
DATE    OBJ No
NA  Leo     12
NA  Jhon    12
NA  Ale     13
NA  Juan    13
NA  Duas    13
NA  Doi     76
NA  Doi     78
NA  Doi     80
NA  Doi     82
NA  Doi     84
NA  Doi     86
NA  Doi     88
NA  Doi     90
NA  Doi     92
NA  Doi     94
NA  Doi     96
NA  Doi     98
NA  Doi    100
NA  Doi    102
NA  Doi    104
```

Esto me hace falta para filtar en el DataFrame por las horas en el dia

```
data <- filter(data ,hour(Date) == 0)
```

Y me devuelva

```
DATE    OBJ           No
2018-09-24-00   Leo   12
2018-09-24-00   Jhon  12
2018-09-24-00   Juan  13
```

Si me pueden ayudar a poder castear este la columna DATE a date completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente los `Factor` suelen traernos problemas, pero en este caso tienes otros:

1. El formato que estás usando para convertir a un objeto `Date` no es el adecuado, debiera ser en todo caso algo como esto: `"%Y-%m-%d-%H"`.
2. Por último, ten en cuenta que un `Date` es un dato de fecha únicamente, no permite albergar la parte de la hora, podríamos hacer `as.Date(data$DATE,format="%Y-%m-%d-%H")` sin problemas, pero perdemos la información de la hora.

Solución:

Podrías trabajar con un objeto base `POSIXlt` o `POSIXct` que permiten albergar la información de la hora, por ejemplo: `data$DATE <- as.POSIXlt(data$DATE,format="%Y-%m-%d-%H")`. Sin embargo veo que estás usando el paquete `lubridate` por lo que te recomiendo que directamente uses la función correspondiente al formato: `ymd_h()`:

```
data$DATE <- ymd_h(data$DATE)
data[hour(data$DATE) == 0,]

         DATE  OBJ No
1  2018-09-24  Leo 12
2  2018-09-24 Jhon 12
4  2018-09-24 Juan 13
11 2018-09-24  Doi 86
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo lo que me envias